# EF7 Getting null values for entity's collection of entities which are many to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I am getting null values for the collection of entities nested in my top entity.  How do I properly write my LINQ query so that these values aren't null??

I am using Entity Framework 7 and MVC 6  Here are my classes:

My models:

```
public class WorkStation
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonWorkStation> PersonWorkStations{ get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonWorkStation> PersonWorkStations{ get; set; }
}

public class PersonWorkStation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int WorkStationId { get; set; }
    public WorkStation WorkStation { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonWorkStation>()
            .HasKey(op => new { op.Id });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonWorkStation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Person)
            .WithMany(p => p.PersonWorkStation)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonWorkStation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.WorkStation)
            .WithMany(t => t.PersonWorkStation)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.WorkStationId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

So with that being said, when I bring back a person, and look at the "PersonWorkStation"s collection, the WorkStation property is null.  How can I bring back that entity?

Here is how I am retrieving the data:

```
        var person = _context.Persons
            .Include(p => p.PersonWorkStation)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);

        return person;
```

Again, the person.PersonWorkStations.Workstation entity is null for all items in the person.PersonWorkStations collection.  How do I return this entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer, I needed to add this line:

```
var person = _context.Persons
        .Include(p => p.PersonWorkStation)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.WorkStation)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);

return person;
```